# No consigo mostrar en php el valor máximo de una columna de mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo una base de datos en phpmyadmin con una tabla de rutas.
Necesito obtener el valor máximo de una columna que es double, y para ello hago esto en una función:

```
function larg_ruta(){
    $sql_script="SELECT MAX(Distancia) FROM rutas";
    $resultado=$this->ejecuta_SQL($sql_script);
    echo $resultado;
}
```

Pero me da este error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be
>   converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\curso\Actividad1\rutas.php on
>   line 66

He intentado varias cosas, como fetch, strval, var_dump, print_r, etc, pero no funciona ninguna.

Comment: y cual es el codigo del metodo ejecuta_SQL podrias mostrarlo

Comment: ¿Así no funciona: **`echo $resultado->fetchColumn();`**? Si no funciona dime el error que da. Y, si piensas usar el valor en otra parte que llama a la función, conviene que lo pongas con `return` en vez de con `echo`

Comment: function ejecuta_SQL($sql){
   $resultado=$this->db->query($sql);
   if(!$resultado){
    echo"<h3>No se ha podido ejecutar la consulta: <pre>$sql</pre><p><u> Errores</u>: </h3><pre>";
    print_r($this->db->errorInfo());
    die ("</pre>");
   }
   return $resultado;
  }

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias, funciona. Si lo he puesto con return mejor para que me lo devolviera cuando llamo al método.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDO tiene un método para retornar el resultado cuando se trata de una sola columna como es tu caso, se trata de:

#### [`fetchColumn()`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

> `PDOStatement::fetchColumn` — Devuelve una única columna de la
>   siguiente fila de un conjunto de resultados

Así debería funcionar:

```
function larg_ruta(){
    $sql_script="SELECT MAX(Distancia) FROM rutas";
    $resultado=$this->ejecuta_SQL($sql_script);
    echo $resultado->fetchColumn();
}
```

Si piensas usar el valor en otra parte que llame a la función, conviene que le pongas un `return`:

```
function larg_ruta(){
    $sql_script="SELECT MAX(Distancia) FROM rutas";
    $resultado=$this->ejecuta_SQL($sql_script);
    return $resultado->fetchColumn();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: @CharlyUtrilla considera dar la pregunta por resuelta antes de que pases a otra cosa en tu código. Me alegro de haberte ayudado. Saludos.

Comment: Ya contaba con ello, pero no me deja ahora, necesito esperar 2 minutos mas

Comment: Bien perfecto, he respondido demasiado rápido :), @CharlyUtrilla